# How to parse Tumbling json key format in ksql

Tags: json, apache-kafka, ksqldb

I am using ksql to create a tumbling window table as shown below:

```
CREATE TABLE payments_min_acc_dev_agg AS SELECT accountId, deviceId, entity, COUNT(*) AS trans_count, sum(amount) AS trans_sum, 'Minute' AS window_type FROM payments_account_stream WINDOW TUMBLING (SIZE 1 MINUTE) GROUP BY accountId, deviceId, entity;
```

Sample output generated to topic is:

```
ksql> print PAYMENTS_MIN_ACC_DEV_AGG from beginning limit 10;
Key format: HOPPING(JSON) or TUMBLING(JSON) or SESSION(KAFKA_STRING) or HOPPING(KAFKA_STRING) or TUMBLING(KAFKA_STRING)
Value format: JSON or KAFKA_STRING
rowtime: 2021/11/05 05:41:32.645 Z, key: [{"ACCOUNTID":"account1","DEVICEID":"device27","ENTITY":"Account"}@1636090860000/-], value: {"TRANS_COUNT":1,"TRANS_SUM":0.9183311577480634,"WINDOW_TYPE":"Minute"}, partition: 0
rowtime: 2021/11/05 05:41:33.248 Z, key: [{"ACCOUNTID":"account5","DEVICEID":"device3","ENTITY":"Account"}@1636090860000/-], value: {"TRANS_COUNT":1,"TRANS_SUM":0.14000975612417166,"WINDOW_TYPE":"Minute"}, partition: 0
```

I want to setup a consumer which will do some processing using the **key** and **value**. I understand **value** can be deserialized as a json string but not sure how to deserialize **key**.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The key isn't valid JSON, so there's no key_format you can use for it other than a plain string and try to parse it